# How to cancel all pending alarms

Tags: android

In my app I want to enable the user to delete the alarms that they have set.

Here is how I set the alarms:

```
    ArrayList<Long> alarmDates = DateAndTimeAssistant.turnReminderTimesIntoActualDates(reminderHolder);
    alarms = new ArrayList<Alarm>();
    for (long alarmDate : alarmDates) {
        Alarm alarm = new Alarm();
        alarm.setTimeInMiliseconds(alarmDate);
        alarm.setReminderHolderId(reminderHolder);
        alarm.setTitle("title");
        alarm.setDescription("description");
        alarms .add(alarm);
    }
```

Then I insert them into DB and onSuccess, I do this:

```
DateAndTimeAssistant.addAlarmsToPushNotificationService(alarms);
```

Here is what happens there:

```
for (Alarm alarm : alarms) {
        Calendar alarmCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        alarmCalendar.setTimeInMillis(alarm.getTimeInMiliseconds());

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, PushNotificationReceiver.class);
        intent.putExtra("notificationTitle", alarm.getTitle());
        intent.putExtra("notificationText", alarm.getDescription());


        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, (int) alarmCalendar.getTimeInMillis(), intent, 0); // The second arg is unique id

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE); // Service.ALARM_SERVICE
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmCalendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
    }
```

Now, in a completely different activity from the one that started all this, I want to delete the alarms.

I found the following piece of code in an article :

```
        for (long alarmTime : alarms) { // This is the unique ID of the pendingIntent I created earlier
            PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(a, (int) alarmTime, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

But I dont know what to pass as "intent" here?

EDIT: Following the first answer I got, I changed the code like so:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, PushNotificationReceiver.class);

        for (long alarmTime : alarms) { // This is the unique ID of the pendingIntent I created earlier
            PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(a, (int) alarmTime, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
}
```

But alarms still keep going off after the supposed deletion. What else could have gone wrong?
I now realize that I dont do anything with this PendingIntent Im creating. What should I do with it?

**EDIT 2:**
Now I added an alarm manager and Im passing the pending intents to it, then cancelling them, but still it doesnt work

```
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) a.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(a, PushNotificationReceiver.class);
        for (long alarmTime : alarms) {
            PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(a, (int) alarmTime, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
            // Cancel alarms
            try {
                alarmManager.cancel(pIntent);
            } catch (Exception e) {
               // Cant do anything about it.
            }
        }
```

Comment: The Intent you pass is a duplicate of the one used to create the Alarm entry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create the same `Intent` as the one that you used when creating the alarms. Note that when comparing Intents, the extras are ignored, so you only need

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, PushNotificationReceiver.class);
```

Comment: Well I added this line to my code, and deleted the reminderholder, the alarms from the db and supposedly the alarms from the pending intent but I still keep receiving new notifications. Is there something else I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

you can use below method do cancel alarm

```
 public void cancelAlarm(Context context, int ID) {
        mAlarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        // Cancel Alarm using Reminder ID
        mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, ID, new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class), 0);
        mAlarmManager.cancel(mPendingIntent);

        // Disable alarm
        ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(context, BootReceiver.class);
        PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
        pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I too had same problem . I had to cancel all the pending alarm that was set previously .

I created pending intent with same `requestId` (I saved it to DB while creating alarm , then retrieved it) , then cancelled it.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/46278582/4432176